# OpenVPN server local network access and vpn network access

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn

*first off, apologies if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find a question that matches mine*

I have a home linux server and a remote VPS linux server.

OpenVPN satisfies the requirement of a high speed connection between these 2 servers, however, I am not able to access my home server over my home network since my home server is "not connected" to my home network. I am only able to access it over OpenVPN which has a delay of ~200ms.

So in short, I want to use OpenVPN to have my 2 servers connected as well as access my home server as I would without the vpn *i.e.* >10ms latency

I hope this makes sense?

Possible solutions?

**UPDATE *e.g.***

At home I ssh into my home server with alias `hserv`

so at home I `ssh root@hserv` and I do my thing.

But if I close this ssh session and let hserv connect to the VPN connection, and attempt to reconnect to it with `ssh root@hserv`, I am not able to. This is the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you use `redirect-gateway` so all traffic is going thru VPN and home server is on different subnet then your desktop/laptop.

Easiest solution is to put server and desktop on the same subnet.

Other solution is to force routing to this server via your home gateway router. In OpenVPN client config add:

```
route <home_server_IP> net_gateway
```

This will route packets to server via your home gateway/router.

Comment: I like this, ill give it a try, this seems to be the correct method to achieve this, thanks!

Comment: i know this is ancient, but this worked for me in a similar situation.